# Can we get Google Compute Engine recommendations through API?

Tags: google-compute-engine

We get Google [recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances) in virtual machines UI, such as the following:

[image: Google Compute Engine recommendations for saving money]

Can we fetch these recommendations through an API and apply them as well?

Comment: Even if there was an API, I would not apply these recommendations automatically. They may not make sense for your workload. This is something that a human who understands what the virtual machines are doing should think about and decide.

Comment: I agree VM needs a restart in some recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there’s no way to check and apply the recommendations of GCE instances from an API.

I have forwarded your request to the Specialist Team to make them aware about you request to check and apply the recommendations of GCE instances from an API. I have also created a [public Feature Request in the Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/136650033) on your behalf. When you “star” the request you will receive notifications for any important updates. Like this you can keep track of its progress. Keep in mind that it will still be up to the Specialist team to decide if and when to implement such a possibility to check and apply the recommendations of GCE instances from an API, but I recommend you to stay updated on it.